# The code doesn't work - mysql fetch dimesional array

Tags: php, sql

When I execute the next code,it runs but it doesn't show the picture. Does it allow
to SELECT the columns?
As in the code:

```
$query = "SELECT ID AND nickname FROM tbl_photo";
```

Thank you very much !

```
while($photoID = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<a href=img/'.$photoID[$i].'.php><img src="uploads/'.$photoID[$i].'.jpg" alt="Picture" class="photo" width="800" height="600"/></a>התמונה הועלתה על ידי '.$photoID[$i][$j].'
            <form action="like.php" method="POST" ><input type="image" src="img/like.jpg" width="20" height="20"  name="submit" value="'.$photoID[$i].'"/></form>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `comma` instead of `and` as below

```
$query = "SELECT ID , nickname FROM tbl_photo";
```

Comment: To show nickname in spefic ID, i should write $photo[$i][$j] ?